# утилита date в awk и пробел в формате времени

Tags: дата, awk

так не работает

```
awk -v d=`date -u -d'-10 minutes' +"%d/%b/%Y\ %H:%M:%S"` '{print d}'
```

И так тоже:

```
awk -v d=`date -u -d'-10 minutes' +"%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"` '{print d}'
```

работает только так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
getdate=$(date -u -d'-10 minutes' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
awk -v d="$getdate" ' {print d}'
```

Как передать в awk **без bash** результат работы date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способ передачи данных:

```
awk -v d=04/Jun/2018 11:29:37 'print d'
```

Вы должны указать значения. Кроме того, вам нужны фигурные скобки:

```
awk -v d="04/Jun/2018 11:29:37" '{print d}'
#        ^                    ^  ^       ^
```

все вместе:

```
awk -v d="$(date -u -d'-10 minutes' +"%d/%b/%Y\ %H:%M:%S")" 'BEGIN{print d}'
```

Примечание. Я использую `BEGIN`, чтобы он не дождался ввода из файла или stdin

Comment: (I answered using Google Translate, please feel free to improve the post !)

Answer (score 0):

awk имеет встроенную функцию работы со временем:

```
awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T")}' #<<< 1
```

Вследствии чего отсутствует необходимость в вызове команды date

```
awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T")}' <<< 1 && date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"
  #2019-10-08 11:56:17
  #2019-10-08 11:56:17
```

Как видим вывод времени и даты идентичен и берется из системы

Более подробную информацию можно получить здесь [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)